# Can't upload image using Miles Johnson Uploader

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.3, uploader

I'm developing an application, where in I've created a `products` table that has following attributes.

```
{id, image, warranty-image, created, modified}
```

I'm using `miles johnson 4.3.1 uploader` for uploading images. So I've written `$actsAs` in `Product model` as follows.

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'overwrite' => true,
            'uploadDir' => 'img/products',
            'finalPath' => '',
            'dbColumn' => 'image',
            'transforms' => array(
                'imageLarge' => array(
                    'nameCallback' => 'transformNameCallback',
                    'method' => 'resize',
                    'prepend' => 'large_',
                    'width' => 750,
                    'height' => 100,
                    'aspect' => false
                )
        ),
        'warranty_image' => array(
            'overwrite' => true,
            'uploadDir' => 'img/products',
            'finalPath' => '',
            'dbColumn' => 'warranty_image',
            'transforms' => array(
                'warranty_imageSmall' => array(
                    'nameCallback' => 'transformNameCallback',
                    'method' => 'resize',
                    'prepend' => 'small_',
                    'width' => 150,
                    'height' => 96,
                    'aspect' => false
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'extension' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
            'type' => array('image'),
            'minWidth' => 100,
            'minHeight' => 100,
            'filesize' => 5242880
        ),
        'warranty_image' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'extension' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
            'type' => 'image',
            'minWidth' => 100,
            'minHeight' => 96,
            'filesize' => 5242880
        )
    )
);

public function transformNameCallback($name, $file) {
    return $this->getUploadedFile()->name();
}
```

In `add view` I've written `file inputs` as follows.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); 
echo $this->Form->file('image');
echo $this->Form->file('warranty_image');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

This uploader just uploading only `image` image but not `warranty_image` image. Please help me to get the solution. The work would be more appreciated.

Comment: So is it really _uploading_ only the file selected for `image`, or do you actually mean that it's just _storing_ only the file selected for `image`, ie it's actually _uploading_ both files (the browser sends the data for both files), but the file selected for `warrant_image` is not being stored in the database and/or the filesystem?

Comment: @ndm Its only uploading 'image' file and copying into 'table' but its not happening to 'warranty_image'.

Comment: So if this is really the case, then what does the generated HTML form code, and the request being sent (check `debug($this->request->data)` in your controller) look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

This works very similarly to how you are looking and actually does work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML input tag in view or CakePHP Form Helper Input tag.

```
echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file', 'required' => false, 'label' => 'Select the File to Upload'));
echo $this->Form->input('warranty_image', array('type' => 'file', 'required' => false, 'label' => 'Select the File to Upload'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database table is using "warranty-image" as the field.

But your PHP code is using "warranty_image".

Note the "-" instead of "_"